# How to declare a parameter name with a reserved keyword in Java

Tags: java, parameters, naming-conventions, naming, reserved-words

I need to declare a method like so :

```
public void doSomething(Class class) {
...
}
```

and, of course, the `class` parameter name is not valid as it is a reserved keyword. However, in C# I can dodge that using the `@` character as a prefix. Using the `@` not only that I can 'solve' it but upon compilation, at the 'bytecode' (IL) level the name will be stripped of the `@` character.

Anything similar in Java? All I found was `_` and `$`. The dollar sign is the ugliest of them all, IMHO.

---

**Later edit** : I knew about the `clazz` thingie but I didn't mention it, hoping for something nicer. If that's the best, so be it. Is however some table of correspondence for all the reserved keywords? Something along the lines of :

class -> klass, clazz

switch -> swytch, svvitch
...

---

**Later edit 2** : It's amazing how many snarky comments and useless input can a legitimate, IMHO, question can generate. I almost regret asking it.

---

**Later edit 3** : It seems that in the Java world the best thing to do is to shut up and don't ask anything. Don't bother anyone and, even when noone asked/answered a certain question, keep quiet and don't talk.

Comment: the name "class" is really mandatory for you ?

Comment: Nope, I was just trying to find the limits of the language so I can model my code as close to my liking as I can.

Comment: I recommend changing the programming language, so your OCD can fully control you.

Comment: changing Java? How can that be possible?!

Comment: No, using a different programming language.

Comment: I was being sarcastic.

Comment: "Is however some table of correspondence for all the reserved keywords?" `clas` is also sometimes used for `class`. For `byte` people use `b`, or `value`. That's about it for standard replacements. `switch` doesn't really come up.

Comment: If you dont mind a little obfuscation (and being loathed by your fellow programmers), just use some replacement unicode characters, e.g. U+0455 for "s": `public static void frobnicate(Class claѕѕ)` works fine. More "readable" are `claśś` `clașș` or `claʂʂ`. I leave it to you to find their unicode characters :-)

Comment: I'm mystified by your repeated edits complaining about snarky comments. No-one is saying anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. There is no way. Keywords are reserved and cannot be used. Escaping with some strange prefix (like in C#) is in my opinion no proper solution as this makes the code just uglier and less readable.

You can use `type` or `clazz` in your special case.

Answer (score 3):

The de facto standard is `Class clazz`. You'll see it in many APIs.

Comment: exactly! I've seen it and almost puked on it... :-S

Comment: I was rather looking for some generic solution. What if my parameter is called switch?

Comment: If these are your biggest problems, you're the luckiest programmer I've met.

Comment: I know `clazz` is standard, but I've always used `klass`. Much less ugly.

Comment: klass is definitely more classy... so to speak ;)

Comment: I get paid based on the functionality of my code. I'm not having it enter the Miss Code Universe contest. Spending time deciding between class/clazz/klass is time away from doing something useful with the code.

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time then.

Answer (score 1):

A common convention is to misspell the parameter name. In your case you would call the parameter `clazz`:

```
public void doSomething(Class clazz) {
...
}
```

I know it's ugly but it is the solution adopted by the Java community.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use the keywords as parameter name or variable name in java (same sensitive).

There are couple of alternatives:

- Change the case of the parameter. Java is case sensitive, so it will not treat the parameter as a reserved word.
- Use different name which sounds same as reserved word.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is `clazz`. It is more readable.

```
public void doSomething(Class clazz) {
 ...
}
```